# When does mid / late game phase begins?

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

I'm not sure if it's late game either by champion level or by the game time.

People say "early phase you won't do damage, but you do at mid game"

Anyway to refer when do these phases begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upvoted both other answers because they are close but I think their answers are still slightly off.

**Early game:**

Each player sticks to their associated role/lane.

**Mid Game:**

First tower or 2 goes down.  People begin regularly leaving lanes in order to try helping push other objectives and grouping up.

**Late game:**

1 or more players have 3-4 full items.  (Sometimes you hear someone say something like **Jax got to his late game really fast after being fed** or **they never got a chance to reach late game after being shut down so hard**.)

These answers are pretty similar to the others, but I think it gives a little bit more important info about what each part of the game is.

Answer (score 2):

Generally early phase is when you are laning. Once you leave your lane and start going to different lanes for long durations (not just ganks), it is usually considered mid game. Late game is when people are starting to reach full builds or reaching level 18.

Comment: I'd say late game is when 5v5 teamfights are taking place regularly

Comment: @Katustrawfic Some games this happens really early or never happens at all.  Some people split push all day long and never group.  I think it's a better relation to time/items.  I'd consider it late game when people have about 3 or 4 full items.

Answer (score 2):

It varies from game to game, but in 5v5 SR matches, it typically is as follows:

**Early Game**:

This is the start of the game. Each player is playing their role (jungle, adc, support, etc.)

**Mid Game**:

Mid game typically begins when dragon is regularly being contested.

**Late Game**

Late game starts when 5v5 team fights (or 4v4+1 / split push) becomes regular and when baron is regularly being contested (or defended).

Comment: I'd say mid game is when the first towers go down and your team begins to group.  Dragons can be contested in the first 10 min after a successful gank and I don't consider that early game.

Comment: Towers going down doesn't always necessarily mean people start leaving lanes, especially top.

Often top players will stay in their lane all game.

I do agree, though - gank then dragon doesn't count as contesting dragon.

Comment: Yes, I said towers go down **and** grouping.  I'd still consider that contesting though.  Often the non dead lane and/or jungler will try to contest the dragon.